# Ethereum concurrency of different contract accounts

Tags: concurrency, ethereum, smartcontracts

I want to know the meaning of next statement:
"There's no currency in ethereum. It's single threaded."

Let's think of two transactions T1 and T2 implemented by different smart contracts, mined by different nodes, and executed in next order.

1. T1 looks up a state of account A. The value is a1.
2. T2 updates the state of A from a1 to a2.
3. T1 updates a state of account B from b1 to b1 + a1. a1 is the value looked up in step 1.
4. T2 is mined in block number n, then T1 is mined in block n+1.

Is this possible in Ethereum?

What happens if T1 and T2 are run by two different functions from a single smart contract instance?
Is it the same if T1 and T2 are transactions executed by the same function of a single contract instance?

Similar questions are about the status of single account which is serialzed by the block order. I want to know ethereum concurrency among many accounts or smart contract instances.

Solidity code may look like below:

```
contract T2Contract {
    uint public s1;
    function T2(uint updated) public {
        s1 = updated;
    }
}

contract T1Contract {
    uint public s2;
    address t2Address;
    constructor(address _t2Addr) {
        t2Address = _t2Addr;
    }

    function T1() public {
        uint updated = T2Contract(t2Address).s1();
        // do something takes long time
        s2 = s2 + updated;
    }
}
```

The 1st question is whether T1Contract_instance.T1() and T2Contract_instance.T2() can be interleaved or not.

Answer (score 0):

> mined by different nodes, and executed in next order.

This is not possible. The minimum unit of atomicity in Ethereum is a block. If the same transaction or conflicting transaction (so called invalid state change) is included in two different blocks, one of the blocks is invalid and is rejected by Ethereum network. If there is a block producer that keeps producing or broadcasting invalid blocks, they will be kicked out from the network/slashed. Eventually, there is going to be only one blockchain chain tip that is accepted by all nodes.

Comment: Please refer to the solidity code just added in the question. It must be a difficult task for T1()'s miner to find out whether T2.s1 has been updated in between the transaction. So I guess parallel execution in this level may exist in Ethereum.

Comment: Sorry, you did not understand the answer. Parallel execution is not possible. The code is run by the block producer, nobody else for modifying EVM state, and block producer never runs transaction in parallel. Thus, no code is run parallel.